# Create files inside folders with nested loops and arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, nested

I am trying to create 2 folders and some files inside them. But it can't create more than the 1st folder and the 1st file. Code says it can't create the 1st folder since it is exist. Don't even try to create the rest of the files and folders.

Here is what I tried

```
    #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    declare -a arrRel=(rel20 rel21)
    declare -a arrVar=(pt_el pt_mu)
    declare -a arrVarTitle=("electron p_T" "muon p_T")

for i in "${arrRel[@]}"
do
    mkdir "${arrRel[$i]}"
    cd "${arrRel[$i]}"

    for j in "${arrVar[$j]}"
    do
        textFile=text_${arrRel[$i]}_${arrVar[$j]}.txt
        targetDir=Desktop/samples                                                                                                                     

        cat >${textFile} <<EOF
        "some tex"    
EOF                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    done #arrVar                                                                                                                                                                                            

    cd ../ #cd arrRel                                                                                                                                                                                       

done #for loop over releases
```

To sum up, there should be 2 folders, rel20 and rel21 and two text files in both. But I just get the folder rel20 and just one text file in it.

I'd appreciate if you can point me why this doesn't work.

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop, `i` = `rel20`.  What is `${arrRel[rel20]}`?

Comment: I'd recommending against using `cd` like this in scripts; it's too easy for some error (either execution or logic) to throw the `cd` sequence off, and you wind up creating files in unexpected locations. Rather than `cd somedir` followed by `cat >somefile`, use `cat >somedir/somefile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from what you posted, that his is what you are looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arrRel=(rel20 rel21)
declare -a arrVar=(pt_el pt_mu)
declare -a arrVarTitle=("electron p_T" "muon p_T")

for i in "${arrRel[@]}"
do
    mkdir "$i"
    cd "$i"

    for j in "${arrVar[@]}"
    do
        textFile=text_$i_$j.txt
        targetDir=Desktop/samples                                            

        cat >${textFile} <<EOF
        "some tex"
EOF

    done #arrVar

    cd ../ #cd arrRel

done
```

Not sure what your intent for arrVarTitle is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I intend to use the 3rd array inside the text file. If it is text file of pt_el, it should contain "electron p_T" inside the text.

Comment: It can create also the 2nd folder now, there are only one text file in both, which is pt_el. it doesn't produce pt_mu.

Comment: you mean ""electron p_T""  inside the array decleration?

Comment: That is strange, when I run it it create both files.

Comment: I just ignore it for now, but still I have only the first text tfile

Comment: You are using textFile=text_$i_$j.txt correct? It should create a unique name for each pass.

Comment: you are right, it works well for yours. I am messing up somewhere.

Comment: Maybe copy and past mine and then compare with yours using diff to see where the difference is.

Comment: accidentally keep the wrong version in the line `for j in "${arrVar[@]}"`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Also, as point out by Gordon Davisson, textFile=text_${i}_${j}.txt is probably safer to use.

Answer (score 2):

You're indexing the arrays incorrectly.  Frankly, the arrays are adding no value, and they're not worth the confusion.  Just do:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                 

for i in rel20 rel21; do
    (   # This open paren is important
        mkdir -p $i
        cd $i

        for j in pt_el pt_mu; do
            textFile=text_$i_$j.txt
            targetDir=Desktop/samples                                                                                                                     

            cat >${textFile} <<-EOF
            "some tex"    
            EOF                                                                                                                                                                                                         

        done                                                                                                                                                                                           
    ) # end subshell to recover previous working directory
done
```

Comment: I see. thank you very much. However inside each text files I also want to get use of the 3rd array. For example, in the 2nd text file, I want to insert the 2nd element of the 3rd array and in the 1st text file, I want to insert the 1st element of the 3rd array. That's why I'd appreciate if you can also tell me what is wrong with the indicies.

Comment: Also I am going to increase the number of elements of each array. it would be easier to handle I suppose.

Comment: You need to use braces to delimit at least the first variable reference, i.e. `textFile=text_${i}_$j.txt` instead of `textFile=text_$i_$j.txt`. Otherwise, it parses the underscore as part of the variable name. I'd use braces on both of them, just for symmetry: `textFile=text_${i}_${j}.txt`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, both cases, with and without braces, are working the same.